# In spark MLlib, How do i convert string to integer in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

As i know, MLlib supports only interger.
Then i want to convert string to interger in scala.
For example, I have many reviewerID, productID in txtfile.

```
reviewerID    productID
03905X0912    ZXASQWZXAS
0325935ODD    PDLFMBKGMS
...
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"As i know, MLlib supports only interger."_ What do you want to do with the integers? What algorithm are you going to use. It'd be much easier to offer a solution to your **real** issue. Is this ALS perhaps? Or any other recommendation algorithm?

Comment: I will use ALS algorithm, matrix factorization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringIndexer` is the solution. It will fit into the ML pipeline with an estimator and transformer. Essentially once you set the input column, it computes the frequency of each category and numbers them starting 0. You can add `IndexToString` at the end of pipeline to replace by original strings if required.

You can look at ML Documentation for "Estimating, transforming and selecting features" for further details.

In your case it will go like:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer 

val indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("productID").setOutputCol("productIndex") 
val indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
indexed.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new row with a unique id for each reviewerID, productID. You can add a new row in the following ways.

By `monotonicallyIncreasingId`:

```
import spark.implicits._
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("123xyx", "ab"),
  ("123xyz", "cd")
)).toDF("reviewerID", "productID")
data.withColumn("uniqueReviID", monotonicallyIncreasingId).show()
```

By using `zipWithUniqueId`:

```
val rows = data.rdd.zipWithUniqueId.map {
  case (r: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(id +: r.toSeq)
}

val finalDf = spark.createDataFrame(rows, StructType(StructField("uniqueRevID", LongType, false) +: data.schema.fields))

finalDf.show()
```

You can also do this by using `row_number()` in SQL syntax:

```
import spark.implicits._
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("123xyx", "ab"),
  ("123xyz", "cd")
)).toDF("reviewerID", "productID").createOrReplaceTempView("review")
val tmpTable1 = spark.sqlContext.sql(
  "select row_number() over (order by reviewerID) as id, reviewerID, productID from review")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: At By using zipWithUniqueId,  An error has occured.                      scala> val rows = data.rdd.zipWithUniqueId.map {
     | case (r: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(id +: r.toSeq)
     | }
<console>:29: error: not found: type Row
       case (r: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(id +: r.toSeq)
                ^
<console>:29: error: not found: value Row
       case (r: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(id +: r.toSeq)